# Error al listar un base de datos Json con PHP

Tags: php, json

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos Json en donde están listados los cliente y sus planes, pero cuando trato de obtener los datos del usuario tengo este error: ***Notice: Undefined index: tipo in...***

Base de datos:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Pablo",
        "username": "Lopez Vega",
        "password": "contrasenia1234",
        "email": "pablolopez@mail.com",
        "phone": "+541155458888",
        "id": 1014068,
        "plan":[{
            "tipo": "plan 1",
            "valor": 1.99
        }]
    },
```

Función

```
function getuser(){
    return json_decode(file_get_contents('json_db/db.json'), true);
}

function getuserid($id){
    $users = getuser();
    foreach($users as $user){
        if($user['id'] == $id){
            return $user;
        }
    }

    return null;
}



$userid = $_GET['id'];
$user = getuserid($userid);


<h1>User: <?=$user['name']?></h1>
<h4>Email: <?=$user['email']?></h4>
<h4>Plan: <?=$user['plan']['tipo']?></h4>
```

No puedo obtener el tipo de plan ni el valor y no sé como resolverlo.

Agradezco de antemano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que dentro del indice `plan` tienes otro arreglo, para acceder a el sería de la siguiente forma:

```
<h4>Plan: <?=$user['plan'][0]['tipo']?></h4>
```

Comment: Gracias MR, quise poner como índice 0, pero lo hice mal y ahora veo porque .